# Wrong UI Component Deleted When Validating User Input React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

essentially I have a KanbanBoard-ish app I'm trying to develop and I'm getting some strange behavior when I call my delete function from my validation function. The code is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rmpmn17kp) on codesandbox. The main issue is that when there are multiple cards and I try to delete a `card` with an onBlur event, the card where the event occurs is not deleted but another empty card is. It works as expected if all other cards in a column have text. Please ignore the dnd code, as it came after the original problem.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Here is the logic with App.js

```
  state = { list: list }

  handleChange = (e, col) => {
    let eid = parseInt(e.target.id)
    let updatedList = this.state.list.map(obj => {
      if (obj.id === col) {
        let card = { text: e.target.value }
        obj.cards[eid] = card
      }
      return obj
    })
    this.setState({ list: updatedList })
  }


  setText = (e, col) => {
    if (e.target.value === "") {
      e.target.placeholder = "YOU MUST ENTER TEXT. THIS BOX WILL CLOSE NOW"
      e.persist()
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.delete(e, col)
      }, 3000)
      return
    }

  }

  delete = (e, col) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let eid = parseInt(e.target.id)
    let updatedList = this.state.list.map(obj => {
      if (obj.id === col) {
        obj.cards = obj.cards.filter((c,i) => i !== eid)
        //obj.counter--
      }
      return obj
    })
    this.setState({ list: updatedList })
  }

  add = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let eid = parseInt(e.target.id)
    let updatedList = this.state.list.map(obj => {
      if (obj.id === eid) {
        let card = {text:""}
        obj.cards.push(card)
        obj.counter++
      }
      return obj
    })
    this.setState({ list: updatedList })
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`map` returns an item for each item it iterates through.  Maybe using `filter` would help in the case.  I'm assuming that your `splice` is making the order of `this.state.list` get crazy and confusing.

```
let updatedList = this.state.list.filter(obj => obj.id !== col);
```

Not sure if `col` or `eid` is the correct thing to compare to, but that will get you a new list with all of the previous items except for the one whose id matches the id you're trying to delete.

---

Glancing at your codesandbox, there are some issues.  To boil it down to a high level - each card should have an immutable ID, that you can use to delete it.  You're using the index of the card in an array and combined with who knows what else.  You've lost your source of truth, which is extra important when you are allowing the user to alter the order of an array.  Your card should fire the delete function you pass it from its parent.  It should just take the id of that card, filter that out of the current state, and set the new state.  You're making this overcomplicated.

Parent -

```
state = { list : [{id: 1, ...other card stuff}, {...more cards}] };

delete = id => {
    const newList = this.state.list.filter(item => item.id !== id);
    this.setState({ list: newList };
}

render = () => {
    const { list } = this.state;

    return list.map(item => (
        <Card
             {...item}
             onDelete={this.delete}
        />
    ))
}
```

Card -

```
// whenever you need to delete this card 
this.props.onDelete(this.id);
```

Comment: the problem isn't the `column` value but the obj.cards is being updated correctly yet the wrong one is being deleted. Check my App.js on Codesandbox.

Comment: Best to not link to other pages on StackOverflow.  If those links break in the future, any comments or answers referring to them here are rendered (pun not intended) confusing or useless.  Post the relevant parts of your code here please.

Comment: I have read your post and understand what I need to do by changing my list structure and keeping my state immutable, I didn't even consider that user interaction would be a source of error. Thanks so much, I learned a lot from what you wrote... but it didn't solve the problem.